# Android UncaughtExceptionHandler to finish app

Tags: android, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I want to close the app after logging an unhandled exception. After searching here i made the following:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    //uncaught exceptions
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

    // handler listener
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            //logging code
            //..........

            //call the default exception handler
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);

        }
    };

    public MyApplication() {
        defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(_unCaughtExceptionHandler);
    }
}
```

After calling `defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);` i tried to call `System.exit()` and also  `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` (even i found some posts where is told to use both). The problem is that im getting a black screen and i have to force the app exit with the phone task manager. What am i doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: why do you need to call System.exit? If your want to close your application you can just call finsih(); on activity

Comment: yes, but the problem is that im catching the exceptions on the Application object, not in the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i resolved this making a class implementing the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` interface:

```
public class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private BaseActivity activity;
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

    public MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(BaseActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    public void setActivity(BaseActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

        //LOGGING CODE
        //........

        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);

    }
}
```

In the `BaseActivity` i added the following code:

```
//exception handling
private static MyUncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    if(_unCaughtExceptionHandler == null)
        _unCaughtExceptionHandler = new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    else
        _unCaughtExceptionHandler.setActivity(this);

    if(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() != _unCaughtExceptionHandler)
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(_unCaughtExceptionHandler);
}
```

I know its the same code i have in the question, but somehow its working now. When i have more free time i will look this deeply to find the root cause and post it